# cURL form post with Javascript & postback ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, curl

I'm having an issue trying to submit a form for a medical website to determine a user's name based on their registration number or their national ID number. An example Registration Number is MPS0753602

Site in question: http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/

I can do an initial query to generate the second input form which is generated using a dopostback when clicking on one of the options, in this case clicking on "Registration Number". My issue is that if I fill in all the fields as examined by FireCurl I get a server error, even if I fill them in identically. I think it has something to do with the Javascript on the page.

My code:

```
<?php
    // Specify a cookie file
    $cookiefile = '/var/www/hpcsa/cookies.txt';
    $client = new Login($cookiefile);
    // Retrieve page first to store cookies
    $page = file_get_contents("http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/");
    // scrape __VIEWSTATE value
    $start = strpos($page, '__VIEWSTATE" value="') + 20;
    $end = strpos($page, '"', $start);
    $viewstate = substr($page, $start, $end - $start);
    // scrape __EVENTVALIDATION value
    $start = strpos($page, '__EVENTVALIDATION" value="') + 26;
    $end = strpos($page, '"', $start);
    $eventvalidation = substr($page, $start, $end - $start);

    // Do our actual query
    $form_data = array(
        'SearchChkb$0' => 'on',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
        '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventvalidation,
        '__LASTFOCUS' => '',
        '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewstate,
        'rgReg_No' => 'rbReg_NoExact',
        'txtReg_No' => 'MPS0753602'
    );
    $page = $client -> get("http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/", $form_data);
    echo($page);

    // cURL wrapper class
    class Login {
        private $_cookiefile;

        public function __construct($cookiefile) {
            if (!is_writable($cookiefile)) {
                throw new Exception('Cannot write cookiefile: ' . $cookiefile);
            }
            $this -> _cookiefile = $cookiefile;
        }

        public function get($url, $data = false) {
            // Setup cURL
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

            // Is there data to post
            if (!empty($data)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            }
            return curl_exec($ch);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're _likely_ dealing with _event and/or viewstate_ validation in ASP.Net which restricts POST(back) from external application/s. In other words, _external_ POSTs are rejected (anti "spoofing" measure)

Comment: It would seem that way, I see this code in the response after the initial query:
`<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>`